# how to install Blogger API to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, libraries, blogger

I'm making an app which gathers public data from a blog. I infered I should use the blogger api. I downloaded it from [here](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/api-lib/java) . Since I have never used 3rd party libraries in android I don't know how to actually use it in the app. How do I do that?

I am using Android Studio.

Detailed step-wise instructions appreciated :)

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Comment: No. I did what he said and searched on some more stackoverflows. My gradle build finally succeeded but I'm still not able to use the library. I'm still searching I'll update when I find something.

Comment: Question is marked duplicate. Add a new one if you have any other issues

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted contains the instructions to use the library via Gradle, eg (in your ´build.gradle´):

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-blogger:v3-rev55-1.23.0'
}
```

Comment: I tried it. Im getting:
Error:(30, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'Test' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
<a href="fixGradleElements">Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project</a></li><li>The project 'Test' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>

Comment: @ParamdeepSinghObheroi Please, update your question with your (presumably two) build.gradle files, so we can see what's happening, but it appears that you aren't using the last Gradle plugi version on your project